# How can I make a call to desired function using Closure object?

Tags: php

I created a basic class to play with Closure object a bit. I don't understand the behaviour of this application/closures so I wanted to ask a few things. My mind is pretty cloudy at the moment so I don't know why something runs or why not.

```
<?php

class Route
{
     public static $bindings = array();
     public static $dispatch = array();

     public static function bind($bind)
     {
         self::$bindings[] = $bind;
     }

     public static function getAllBindings()
     {
         return (array) self::$bindings;
     }

     public static function get($binding, Closure $dispatch)
     {

         if(in_array($binding, self::$bindings))
         {
             if(is_callable($dispatch))
             {
                 return call_user_func($dispatch);
             }
             else
             {
                 die("Dispatch method is not callable.");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             die("Binding is not found in bindings array.");
         }
     }

     public static function test()
     {
         echo "Test ran!";
     }
 }
```

Basically, we bind bindings (such as /admin, /account, /profile etc.) Then, we try to call a method using closure.

```
// Let's bind account and admin as available bindings
    Route::bind('account');
    Route::bind('admin');

// Let's try doing a get call with parameter "account"
    Route::get('account', function() { 
         // This is where I'm stuck. See below examples:
         // Route::test();
         // return "test";
         // return "testa";
         // return self::test();
    });
```

If you checked above, here are my questions:

1. If I provide a non-existent method, `is_callable` check does not run and I get a `php fatal error`. Isn't `is_callable` a valid check for checking inexistent methods? Why does it happen?
2. If I provide `return "Test";` in the closure, is my `$closure parameter in get method` going to contain `"Test"` string?
3. Can I pass a methods from different classes inside the closure? Like:

   ```
   Route::get('account', function () {
       if(User::isLoggedIn() !== true)
            return Error::login_error('Unauthorized.');
   });
   ```
4. If so, in which scope this call is being made? PHP's scope in closure, or does call_user_func call it inside Route class' scope since it is passed to it via closure? (To clear it a bit more, PHP's scope may do `$route->get` but Closure scope may use `$this->get`)
5. Is there any way to dump Closure object like var_dump/print_r to see it's contents?

A short guidance will get me going. I know PHP but using closures is pretty new to me.

Thanks alot and I appreciate your replies.

Comment: this question seems to be purely php, would you mind removing the oop tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need that `is_callable()` check as the `Closure` type hint in the method declaration already ensures this. Also you don't need `call_user_func()`. This will give you the following `get()` method:

```
 public static function get($binding, Closure $dispatch)
 {

     if(!in_array($binding, self::$bindings))
     {
         die("Binding is not found in bindings array.");
     }

     return $dispatch();
 }
```

**Note** : Currently the `$binding` param will just being used in a check, but not as a param to `$dispatch()`, what would I have expected. I can't see a reason for that. You should rethink this part

---

I found another hidden question in your post:

```
// Let's try doing a get call with parameter "account"
Route::get('account', function() { 
    // This is where I'm stuck. See below examples:
    // Route::test();
    // return "test";
    // return "testa";
    // return self::test();
});
```

It should look like:

```
// Let's try doing a get call with parameter "account"
Route::get('account', function() { 
    // Both should work well:
    // Route::test();
    // .. or 
    // return self::test();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What should I return for the $closure object, if I want to execute test method? 'test', 'self::test' or 'Route::test'? I'll be real glad if you can explain all my questions shortly so I can understand what's going on.

Comment: You can return everything from a closure that you can return from a *regular* function

Comment: Let's say I wanted to return "$this->test" as callback method and expected Route->test() method to execute. In which scope does it get handled? Inside Route class (so Route class may consider $this as their own class) or index.php's scope (so I can pass other things like $event->add())?

Comment: None of them. A closure has per default it's own scope in PHP. But you can import variables from other scopes into the closure scope using the `use` statement, or the method `Closure::bind()` or `Closure::bindTo()`... Like this: `$f = function () { echo 'f'; };` and then `$f->bindTo($this);`

Comment: So, if I want to call $event->add inside the closure object, I have to do use($event) after closure declaration?

Comment: Yes, or bind it to the scope where `$event` is defined

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30381/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-imaqtpie)

Comment: @Imaqtpie You've asked for an example, how to get the source code of a closure, check [this article](http://www.metashock.de/2013/05/dump-source-code-of-closure-in-php/?preview=true&preview_id=779&preview_nonce=0d3aca822f) :)

Comment: I never expected you would also reply on that. Thanks alot for all the knowledge you passed to me during chat. Really appreciated!